# print backslash in R strings

Tags: r, knitr

GNU R 3.02

```
> bib <- "\cite"
Error: '\c' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\c"
> bib <- "\\cite"
> print(bib)
[1] "\\cite"
> sprintf(bib)
[1] "\\cite"
>
```

how can I print out the string variable bib with just one "\"?

(I've tried everything conceivable, and discover that R treats the "\\" as one character.)

I see that in many cases this is not a problem, since this is usually handled internally by R, say, if the string were to be used as text for a plot.

But I need to send it to LaTeX. So I really have to remove it.

I see `cat` does the trick. If cat could only be made to send its result to a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `cat`.

```
bib <- "\\cite"
cat(bib)
# \cite
```

---

You can remove the `##` and `[1]` by setting a few options in `knitr`. Here is an example chunk:

```
<<newChunk,echo=FALSE,comment=NA,background=NA>>=
bib <- "\\cite"
cat(bib)
@
```

which gets you `\cite`. Note as well that you can set these options globally.

Comment: The author *did* use `cat`. Read to the end of the OP! :-)

Comment: @SimonO101 I missed that.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the options! Much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in an inline code section?

Answer (score 6):

There is no backslash in the character element "\cite". The backslash is being interpreted as an escape and the two character "\c" is being interpreted as a cntrl-c. Except that is not a recognized character. See `?Quotes`. The second version has only one backslash followed by 4 alpha characters. Count the characters to see this:

```
nchar("\\cite")
[1] 5
```

Comment: I see now that there's a typo in my message and have edited it. Apparenyly, stackoverflow treats "\\" as "\" when it creates output. Which is, in my experience, expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

OK,

```
<<echo=FALSE,result='asis'>>
result <- cat(rbib)
@
```

does the trick (without the `result <-` bit, `[1]` is added). It just feels kludgy.