# Concatenating special character strings in paste and paste0

Tags: r, string, escaping, paste

I wonder how to concatenate special character string in `paste0` like **\item**.

```
paste0("\item", "b")


paste0("a", "b")
#> [1] "ab"
  paste0("a", "\b")
#> [1] "a\b"
paste0("\item", "\b")
#> Error: '\i' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\i"
```

**Edited**

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
  head(airquality) %>%
  mutate(Ozone1 = cat(paste0("\\item{", Ozone)))
#> \item{41 \item{36 \item{12 \item{18 \item{NA \item{28
#>   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
#> 1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
#> 2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
#> 3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
#> 4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
#> 5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
#> 6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

Comment: This? `cat(paste0("\\item", "b"))` You need to escape the slash. If you omit `cat`, it will keep both slashes.

Comment: Thanks @Sotos for your very useful answer. Would appreciate if you guide how to use this in `mutate` function from `dplyr` package.

Comment: [See linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19333894/680068), `nchar(paste0("\\item", "b"))` gives 6, meaning there is only 1 backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you need to escape the backslash. In order to print it with a single backslash, you need to use `cat`. Otherwise, it is interpreted as an escape. For this reason, you will not be able to add it as is in a data frame. For example,

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% mutate(new = paste0("\\item", "b")) #both backslashes are printed
```

We can't use `cat` inside `mutate`. The backslash is escaped. To define a single backslash, you need to use double backslash in the string.

Find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366812/add-backslash-before-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Thanks @Sotos for your answer. I need only one backslash. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: I added an explanation.